# How to position a div above another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code is:

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div id="banner">
        <div class="container">
          <p class="para">hello world</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container banner-bottom">
            <div class="card card-primary text-center z-depth-2 contact-main-text">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <p class="white-text">Please fill out the form below and ESC 
staff will be in contact with you shortly.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.para{
  color:white;
  background: red;
    padding:70px;
    text-align:center;}

  .white-text{
      background:green;
      padding:20px;}
```

Output is: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/3vKa2vIMCf)
And i want:

[image]

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you post an example of your expected result-output?

Comment: @Hackerman "And i want:" , he wants the bootply to look like his posted picture.

Comment: The css translate property might be useful here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve what you need. What have you tried?

Comment: Check if my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of position could help you, here's a rough version that will hopefully get you thinking what you need to do:

```
#banner { position:relative;}
.banner-bottom { position: absolute; top:75%;right:0;bottom:auto;left:0; }
```

Heres a forked bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Imuh4wUj50

Answer (score 4):

You can set negative top margin to overlay the second div, see the live example:

```
<div class="container banner-bottom" style="margin-top:-5%;padding:2%">
```

http://www.bootply.com/MorC45NB4V

PS: I have used inline css just to show, avoid inline css.

Comment: i do not want negative margin.i want to to it with position property.

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses jQuery and some calculations. My calculation works even if you move the elements around the document. I also used CSS for the margins you wanted.

**jQuery**

```
//location of bottom of the red container
var bottomOfContainer = $('#onTopOfMe').offset().top + $('#onTopOfMe').height();
//gets the bottom 4th of the red container
var placement = bottomOfContainer - ($('#onTopOfMe').height() / 4);
//setter of top for green container
$('#placeMe').offset({"top": placement});
```

**CSS**

```
 p.white-text{
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eA3hfeQt8T)

Answer (score 1):

1) In case you want your lower banner to have a full width:

You could add *position: relative;* to the lower banner and position it adding a bottom value and use margin to create the same visual effect asked in the question.

```
.banner-bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
  margin: 0 40px;
}
```

2) In case you don't need to have a banner with full width and just center it, then no need to use margins. Remember to set one parent as *position: relative;*:

```
 #banner { position:relative;}

.banner-bottom { 
  position: absolute;
  top:75%;
  right:0;
  bottom:auto;
  left:0;
 }
```

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/PWOPjY

Answer (score 1):

Here's my [solution](http://codepen.io/johndurso/pen/2b400d8d26ffcdb6b853484ae10be301/) for this.

Basically just make the position of the card block "relative", position the "top" position accordingly, then set the margin to "auto" to center it.

```
.card-block {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```